# Filtering table columns on button click

Tags: jquery

I have written the code as index.php in my own directory which has a button named "Administrator only" and on click of this button, the page is directed to the following link which is connected to another webpage displaying the table.

```
onClick="javascript:OpenWindow('https://gryphon.rnet.missouri.edu/authtest',20,0,'WindowEnt')"
```

The problem is that I have to filter the columns of the table without copying the database into my directory. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to update the title to this question.  The one you had wasn't great, but I'm not sure if this is what the problem is.  Can you explain your issue a bit more?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am working in my own directory and created index.php file which is just a copy of index.php under the parent directory of mine. the 'authtest' directory is read only for me, but all the actions are performed in a file named 'admin.php' present in 'authtest' directory. this file has the code to perform 7 actions- add, lookup, delete, display all the users with entitlement, display all users and logout.

Comment: I have to display all the users but by filtering based on the entitlements that maches to mine one. I am new to Ajax, so I dont know where to write the code for filtering as ?I have read-only access to "authtest' directory. it is called as I mentioned in the very begining. Please help me.

Comment: The piece of code that is mainly important here is :

Comment: <td align=right width=33%> <Font size=3>
  <form name="Entform" action="Ent.php" method="POST">
     <input type="button" name=submit value="Administrators Only"
        Title='Administrator Access'
     onClick="javascript:OpenWindow('https://gryphon.rnet.missouri.edu/authtest',20,0,'WindowEnt')">
   </form></Font>
</td